# Symfony2 creating and persisting entity relationships

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities `Skin` and `Email`. I want `Email` to be a part of the `Skin` entity, however I can't use the console to update schema automatically right now, and that is  probably why I can't get the relationship to work.

So I want to store all the Emails in the Email entity, and I want to assign an email to a desired Skin. So the relationship should me OneToOne.

I am not an expert in MySQL relationships so this is what I made by myself:

In my main `Skin` class I created a field in which I want to store the emails id:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Entity\Email", inversedBy="skin")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="email_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $email_id;
```

In the Email class I created the skin field in which I want to show the skins Id:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MediaparkLt\SkinBundle\Entity\Skin", mappedBy="email_id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="skin", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $skin;
```

Now in my CMS I create the new email like this:

```
public function saveAction(Request $request) {
    $item = new Email();
    $type = new EmailType($this->container->getParameter("langs"));
    $form = $this->createForm($type, $item);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    if ($form->isValid()) {    
            $this->upload($form, $item);

            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cms_skin_email_list', array('skin_id' => $item->getId())));
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'item' => $item);
}
```

And this is the form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option) {
    $builder->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'cms.Title'));
    $builder->add('registration_content', 'textarea', array('label' => 'cms.registration.content'));
}
```

Now in mysql I create the relationship like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `skin` ADD CONSTRAINT `emailId` FOREIGN KEY (`email_id`) REFERENCES `lottery`.`email`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Now when I create a new email I still get NULL on both entitites.

Comment: There is no 'skin' field in the form and you don't call $item->setSkin() from the controller action so why would you expect either side of the relationship to be set? I don't see a Skin entity being created. If you are creating one when the Email is created it will not be saved unless you cascade persist from the Email entity.

Comment: The Skin is already created. And in my CMS I select a Skin and in that skin I create a new Email. If the mapping is correct shouldnt the Email assign to the skin automatically? Do I still need to persist the email?

Comment: Yes, you still need to persist the email. I will add an answer referring to an explanation in the relevant doctrine documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create two entities with a one-to-one relationship, both entities need to be persisted either explicitly or by using cascade persist on one side of the relationship. You also need to explicitly set both sides of the relationship.

[Doctrine - Working with Associations - Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)

States:

> Even if you persist a new User that contains our new Comment this code
>   would fail if you removed the call to
>   EntityManager#persist($myFirstComment). Doctrine 2 does not cascade
>   the persist operation to all nested entities that are new as well.

[Doctrine - Working with Associations - Establishing Associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations)

States:

> In the case of bi-directional associations you have to update the
>   fields on both sides

With no cascade persist you need something like this:

```
$skin = new Skin();
$email = new Email();
$skin->setEmail($email);
$email->setSkin($skin);
$em->persist($email);
$em->persist($skin);
$em->flush();
```

With cascade persist on the Skin side of the relationship you can omit `$em->persist($skin)`. Note if you cascade persist you would usually also cascade remove:

```
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Entity\Email", inversedBy="skin", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
```