# Doctrine2 @OneToOne isn't working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a little problem with my @OneToOne relationships. I'm using a lot of @OneToMany, and they work perfectly.

I built the most simple @OneToOne case:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Lemon\RestBundle\Annotation as Rest;

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="TEST")
* @ORM\Entity
* @Rest\Resource(name="test")
*/
class Test
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="CONTENT", type="string")
    */
   private $content;

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Cmt", mappedBy="test", cascade={"persist"})
    **/
   private $cmt;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Lemon\RestBundle\Annotation as Rest;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="CMT")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Rest\Resource(name="Cmt")
 */
class Cmt
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CONTENT", type="string")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Test", inversedBy="cmt")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="test_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $test;
}
```

So, we have just a Test entity with one comment Cmt. Nothing hard.

As you can see, I'm using LemonRestBundle (use Lemon\RestBundle\Annotation as Rest).

In sending this JSON:

```
{
    "content": "test",
        "cmt": {
            "content": "abcd"            
        }
}
```

On that URL: http://localhost/web/web/app_dev.php/api/test

And I've that error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO CMT (CONTENT, test_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [\"adzae\", null]:\\\n\\\nSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 515 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [515] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

I don't know why Doctrine2 (or maybe LemonRestBundle, but I really don't think so...) can't fills TEST_ID with the TEST(ID). This work perfectly fine with my @ManyToOne relationships, that's why I'm really confuse about it.

Do I need to add something in the Test constructor like in @OneToMany ? Equivalent to:

```
$this->cmts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

I've already checked [Doctrine2 Association Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), and their @OneToOne example is exactly the same.

Please, help me!

Comment: Are you explicitly setting both sides of the relationship?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981786/symfony2-creating-and-persisting-entity-relationships/30998277#30998277

Comment: Thank to you for the quick answer! But persists are supposed to be done by the LemonRestBundle. I'm asking @stanlemon if his bundle handles OneToOne cascade persist.